# Minify our external javascripts with webpack

Tags: node.js, symfony, symfony4, webpack-encore

I want to Miniy my JS Files with webpack-encore of Symfony 4.

```
../js/jquery.min.js
../js/clickable.js
../js/myscrips.min.js
```

just minified! not download dependency and not change files.
has any ways to do?!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using webpack with symfony 4, you would just use the command for production to combine and minify:

[Yarn](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/webpack-encore-legacy/production-build):

```
yarn run encore production
```

[NodeJs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/faq.html#how-do-i-deploy-my-encore-assets):

```
./node_modules/.bin/encore production
```

If you haven't setup your "webpackconfig.js" have a look [here](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/frontend.html).